# transforming long data to wide in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

Hi i have data that looks like this :

```
X             snp_id is_severe encoding_1 encoding_2 encoding_0   chisq   p.value  AF_total  AF_LATIN
1 1 chr21-10139833-A-C         0          0          1          7 1.70625 0.191       0.4          0.3      
2 2 chr21-10139833-A-C         1          0          0         13 1.70625 0.191        0.4        0.3
3 3 chr21-10141374-T-C         0          0          1          7 1.70625 0.191        0.5         0.2
4 4 chr21-10141374-T-C         1          0          0         13 1.70625 0.191        0.5          0.2
```

and it continues to the right with

```
            snp_id         REF         ALT
chr21-10139833-A-C         A            C
chr21-10139833-A-C        A              C   
chr21-10141374-T-C         T              C
chr21-10141374-T-C         T             C
```

this data is very long and every snp_id has is_severe 0 and is_sever_1
( in this example the p/chisq values are the same but in the whole data they are different
what i wish to do is to reshape its structure and make it looks like this

```
 snp_id              is_severe_0_encoding_0 is_severe_0_encoding_1 is_severe_0_encoding_2    
chr21-10139833-A-C         7                          0                    1                        
chr21-10141374-T-C        7                           0                    1
```

and the table continues to the right with this:

```
snp_id              is_severe_1_encoding_0 is_severe_1_encoding_1 is_severe_1_encoding_2    
chr21-10139833-A-C         13                         0                    0                        
chr21-10141374-T-C        13                           0                    0
```

and the table continues to the right with this:

`snp_id                    chisq      p.value    Af_total  Af_latin   REF     ALT`
`chr21-10139833-A-C         1.70625      0.191       0.4     0.3       A        C`
`chr21-10141374-T-C         1.70625       0.191      0.5      0.2      T         C`

i saw some answers in stack overflow on this topic but couldn't find  that would fit my problem
for example :
[Converting data from wide to long format when id variables are encoded in column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891956/converting-data-from-wide-to-long-format-when-id-variables-are-encoded-in-column)
[How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

would appreciate any help

code for sample data :

```
snp_id <- c("chr21-10139833-A-C", "chr21-10139833-A-C","chr21-10141374-T-C","chr21-10141374-T-C")
is_severe <- c("0", "1","0","1")
encoding_1=c(0,0,0,0)
encoding_2=c(1,0,1,0)
encoding_0=c(7,13,7,13)
chisq=c(1.70625,1.70625,1.70625,1.70625)
pvalue=c(0.191,0.191,0.191,0.191)
REF=c("A","A","T","T")
ALT=c("C","C","C","C")
AF_TOTAL=c(0.4,0.4,0.5,0.5)
AF_latin=c(0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2)
df <- data.frame(snp_id,is_severe,encoding_1,encoding_2,encoding_0,chisq,pvalue,REF,ALT,AF_TOTAL,AF_latin)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: @mhovd its not the same because I need to  create "new columns" that include the combination of data of number of column example: is sever ==0 and encoding _0 becomes  new column that contains data when the value of is severe is zero at the value  from the encoding _0 column and its "new " name becomes is_sever_0_encoding_0 and for example chr21-10139833-A-C  it has the value 7

Comment: Please post **reproducible data**

Comment: The link you put can answer your question. see tidyr::spread()

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann  what do you mean by summarizing but im sort of creating "new columns " example: is_sever_0_encoding_0 column for the  snp_id chr21-10139833-A-C it has the value 7

Comment: @CatededUr unfortunately i don't understand how to implement this in my case

Comment: This seems like an XYZ-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
df %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = is_severe,
               values_from = matches("encoding"),
               names_glue = "is_severe_{.name}") %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., "(is_severe_)(encoding_.)_(.)", "\\1\\3_\\2")) %>%
   select(snp_id, matches("is_severe"), everything())
# A tibble: 2 × 13
  snp_id             is_severe_0_encoding_1 is_severe_1_encoding_1 is_sev…¹ is_se…² is_se…³ is_se…⁴ chisq pvalue REF   ALT   AF_TO…⁵ AF_la…⁶
  <chr>                               <dbl>                  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 chr21-10139833-A-C                      0                      0        1       0       7      13  1.71  0.191 A     C         0.4     0.3
2 chr21-10141374-T-C                      0                      0        1       0       7      13  1.71  0.191 T     C         0.5     0.2
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​is_severe_0_encoding_2, ²​is_severe_1_encoding_2, ³​is_severe_0_encoding_0, ⁴​is_severe_1_encoding_0,
#   ⁵​AF_TOTAL, ⁶​AF_latin
```

Comment: thank you , but i need the columns  to be in the name combination of example : is_sever=0 , encoding_0 will be the columns name is_severe_0_encoding_0 and the value will be the value of the encoding_0 column when the value of is severe column ==0

Comment: Check out my edited solution - better?

Comment: is it possible to the is_severe_encoding column to come first ( before the chisq, pvalue) and to the names be like : is_severe_0_encoding_0 instead of is_seveere_encoding_0_0. and thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Now finally better?