# How to load and reshape from wide to long format when columns have repeated names and no identifier

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I would like to change from wide to long format in R. However, the original layout of the excelsheet makes this problematic.

Spreadsheet:

| Date | Unit | Day | Treatment | Value | Unit | Day | Treatment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-03-2023 | 1 | 1 | treatment1 | 8.5 | 2 | 1 | treatment2 | 9.4 |
| 01-03-2023 | 1 | 2 | treatment1 | 10.2 | 2 | 2 | treatment2 | 10.5 |

This goes on for more than 200 different units, i.e. it is a very wide spreadsheet and there are more columns than added in this example

# I would like to change the format to the following:

| Date | Unit | Day | Treatment | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-03-2023 | 1 | 1 | treatment1 | 8.5 |
| 01-03-2023 | 2 | 1 | treatment2 | 9.4 |
| 02-03-2023 | 1 | 2 | treatment1 | 10.2 |
| 02-03-2023 | 2 | 2 | treatment2 | 10.5 |

The first problem arises when trying to import the sheet, because R creates unique names for each column by adding numbers sequentially to the names of each column, e.g.

| Date | Unit...2 | day...3 | treatment...4 | value...5 | Unit...6 | day...7 | treatment...8 | value...9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

The second problem is how to  obtain the desired long-format table using pivot_longer (or other alternatives), with grouped/repeated data like this?

The original layout of the spreadsheet cannot be modified since many persons use it and add data to it everyday.

I hope to find a solution using the pivot_longer function, since I'm familiar with this - but I will accept all suggestions with graditude

I found some inspiration from other posts, but these all have the "unit identifiers" added to each column name, whereas I have random unique identifiers for each column generated by R, e.g.   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891956/converting-data-from-wide-to-long-format-when-id-variables-are-encoded-in-column](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

or

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73765965/reshape-from-wide-to-long-with-multiple-columns-that-have-different-naming-patte](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data. Taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be helpful as well.

Comment: What is the command you are using to read in the data?

Comment: Where did you gate `02-03-2023` from? The original data does not have that

Comment: Read the data without the first row. Set up a loop to select the columns, 4 at a time, (looks like from Unit, Day, Treatment, Value, the columns continue in that order?) Something like `df = mydata[, i:i+3]`. Use `rbind()` in the loop to bind them into a table, using the dates as the first column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `pivot_longer()` by just not taking the numbers in the pivot and then creating the column group number after the fact.  Here's an example. First, I make the data in a way that reproduces the format, but without having to read in an external file.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.table(textConnection('
Date    Unit    Day Treatment   Value   Unit    Day Treatment   Value
01-03-2023  1   1   treatment1  8.5 2   1   treatment2  9.4
01-03-2023  1   2   treatment1  10.2    2   2   treatment2  10.5
'), header=TRUE) 
names(dat) <- c("Date", "Unit", "Day", "Treatment", "Value", 
                "Unit", "Day", "Treatment", "Value")
dat <- as_tibble(dat, .name_repair = "unique" )
dat
#> # A tibble: 2 × 9
#>   Date       Unit...2 Day...3 Treatmen…¹ Value…² Unit.…³ Day...7 Treat…⁴ Value…⁵
#>   <chr>         <int>   <int> <chr>        <dbl>   <int>   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 01-03-2023        1       1 treatment1     8.5       2       1 treatm…     9.4
#> 2 01-03-2023        1       2 treatment1    10.2       2       2 treatm…    10.5
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​Treatment...4, ²​Value...5, ³​Unit...6,
#> #   ⁴​Treatment...8, ⁵​Value...9
```

Now, do the pivot. The `number` column identifies the column group (e.g., what would be `Unit_1`, `Day_1`, `Treatment_1`, `value_1`, and then `Unit_2`, `Day_2`, `Treatment_2`, `value_2`, in a more conventional setup.

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(obs = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, obs), names_pattern="(.*)\\.\\.\\..*", 
               names_to = ".value") %>% 
  group_by(obs) %>% 
  mutate(number = 1:n())
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#> # Groups:   obs [2]
#>   Date         obs  Unit   Day Treatment  Value number
#>   <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <chr>      <dbl>  <int>
#> 1 01-03-2023     1     1     1 treatment1   8.5      1
#> 2 01-03-2023     1     2     1 treatment2   9.4      2
#> 3 01-03-2023     2     1     2 treatment1  10.2      1
#> 4 01-03-2023     2     2     2 treatment2  10.5      2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the structure of your data based on the example, but it sounds like one thing that will work is to extract each treatment unit as a sub-df and then `bind_rows` them together. For example if data is read using `as_tibble`'s `universal` column names, you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.table(textConnection('
Date    Unit    Day Treatment   Value   Unit    Day Treatment   Value   Unit    Day Treatment   Value
01-03-2023  1   1   treatment1  8.5 2   1   treatment2  9.4 3   1   treatment1 3.3
01-03-2023  1   2   treatment1  10.2    2   2   treatment2  10.5    3   1   treatment2  5.5
01-04-2023  1   1   treatment1  10.2    2   1   treatment2  10.5    3   1   treatment2  5.5
'), header=TRUE)

(dat <- as_tibble(dat, .name_repair = "unique")
# A tibble: 3 × 13
#  Date        Unit   Day Treatment  Value Unit.1 Day.1 Treatment.1 Value.1 Unit.2 Day.2 Treatment.2 Value.2
#  <chr>      <int> <int> <chr>      <dbl>  <int> <int> <chr>         <dbl>  <int> <int> <chr>         <dbl>
#1 01-03-2023     1     1 treatment1   8.5      2     1 treatment2      9.4      3     1 treatment1      3.3
#2 01-03-2023     1     2 treatment1  10.2      2     2 treatment2     10.5      3     1 treatment2      5.5
#3 01-04-2023     1     1 treatment1  10.2      2     1 treatment2     10.5      3     1 treatment2      5.5

dat |> 
    select(!contains(".")) |> 
    bind_rows(map(1:2, ~{
        d <- select(dat, Date, contains(paste0(".", .x)))
        colnames(d) <- str_remove(colnames(d), "\\.\\d+")
        d
    }))
# A tibble: 9 × 5
#  Date        Unit   Day Treatment  Value
#  <chr>      <int> <int> <chr>      <dbl>
#1 01-03-2023     1     1 treatment1   8.5
#2 01-03-2023     1     2 treatment1  10.2
#3 01-04-2023     1     1 treatment1  10.2
#4 01-03-2023     2     1 treatment2   9.4
#5 01-03-2023     2     2 treatment2  10.5
#6 01-04-2023     2     1 treatment2  10.5
#7 01-03-2023     3     1 treatment1   3.3
#8 01-03-2023     3     1 treatment2   5.5
#9 01-04-2023     3     1 treatment2   5.5
```

For a fully general solution, replace the `1:2` in `map` with e.g. `max(as.double(str_extract(colnames(dat), "\\d+")), na.rm=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Read in the data with `readxl`s `readxlsx` and give each block of *Unit* to *Value* its own id.

Assuming the structure: Date [(Unit Day Treatment Value) x-times]

**rename function**

- `nms[1]` = *Date*, leave as is
- `nblock` = change to amount of blocks
- `nelem` = elements per block (i.e Unit, Day, Treatment, Value)

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

nblock <- 3
nelem <- 4

rnms <- function(nms) c(nms[1], paste0(nms[-1], rep(seq(nblock), each = nelem)))
```

Use `rnms` with `.name_repair` to read data

```
df <- read_xlsx("file.xlsx", .name_repair = rnms)

df                                                                          
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  Date       Unit1  Day1 Treatme…¹ Value1 Unit2  Day2 Treat…² Value2 Unit3  Day3
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 01-03-2023     1     1 treatmen…    8.5     2     1 treatm…    9.4     3     1
2 02-03-2023     1     2 treatmen…   10.2     2     2 treatm…   10.5     3     2
3 03-03-2023     1     3 treatmen…   11.2     2     3 treatm…   11.5     3     3
# … with 2 more variables: Treatment3 <chr>, Value3 <dbl>, and abbreviated
#   variable names ¹​Treatment1, ²​Treatment2
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Getting the long format with `bind_rows`

```
bind_rows(lapply(1:nblock, function(x) 
  setNames(bind_cols(df[1], df[grepl(x, colnames(df))]), 
    unique(gsub("\\d+$", "", colnames(df))))))
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  Date        Unit   Day Treatment  Value
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
1 01-03-2023     1     1 treatment1   8.5
2 02-03-2023     1     2 treatment1  10.2
3 03-03-2023     1     3 treatment1  11.2
4 01-03-2023     2     1 treatment2   9.4
5 02-03-2023     2     2 treatment2  10.5
6 03-03-2023     2     3 treatment2  11.5
7 01-03-2023     3     1 treatment3   8.5
8 02-03-2023     3     2 treatment3  10.2
9 03-03-2023     3     3 treatment3  11.2
```

##### Data

Exported (from .xlsx) as **.csv**

```
% cat file.csv
Date,Unit,Day,Treatment,Value,Unit,Day,Treatment,Value,Unit,Day,Treatment,Value
01-03-2023,1,1,treatment1,8.5,2,1,treatment2,9.4,3,1,treatment3,8.5
02-03-2023,1,2,treatment1,10.2,2,2,treatment2,10.5,3,2,treatment3,10.2
03-03-2023,1,3,treatment1,11.2,2,3,treatment2,11.5,3,3,treatment3,11.2
```